# possible to test the length of an excel cell's text as the cell loses focus?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a solution that will fill excel cells with data being populated by a keyboard emulation device that reads information from tags.  after the data is read the keyboard emulation device will send a postfix character like a TAB or CR to progress to a different cell

I'm trying to determine if it's possible using VBA to test the length of the data that was filled when that cell loses focus from the TAB/CR.  if it's not the correct length I'd like to have the option to either delete the previous cell's contents or display a message box window telling the user there's an issue.

I really don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

EDIT -
Here's the code that's working for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim iLen As Integer

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' bail if more than one cell selected

iLen = Len(Target.Value)    ' get cell data length
If iLen = 0 Then Exit Sub   ' bail if empty data

If Target.Column = 1 Then ' if Col A
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' bail if column header
    If iLen <> 3 Then 'Replace *Your Value* with your length
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'So we don't get an error while clearing
        Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' So Excel while function normal again
    End If
ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then ' if Col B
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' bail if column header
    If iLen <> 7 Then
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your emulator stop sending characters once you've sent the tab/cr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Worksheet_Change` Event

[image: ViewCode]

[image: Worksheet]

[image: Select Change Event]

[image: Final Code]

The code used was:

```
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Len(Target.Value) <> 3 Then 'Replace *Your Value* with your length
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'So we don't get an error while clearing
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' So Excel will function normal again
    End If
End If
```

To test a different length for a different column just add an `else` for example

```
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Len(Target.Value) <> 3 Then 'Replace *Your Value* with your length
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'So we don't get an error while clearing
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' So Excel will function normal again
    End If
Else If Target.Column = 2 then
    If Len(Target.Value) <> 7 Then 
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False 
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True 
    End If

End If
```

In the Event you'd like to test a larger amount of Columns it would be smart to change things around and add a function into your program as Follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Target.Column

        Case 1 'If Target.Column = A
            Call TestValues(Target.Value, 3)
        Case 2 'If Target.Column = B
            Call TestValues(Target.Value, 7)
        Case 7 'If Target.Column = G
            Call TestValues(Target.Value, 1)

    End Select

End Sub

Function TestValues(CellValue As String, LengthLimit As Integer)

    If Len(CellValue) <> LengthLimit Then 'The value and length passed in from the Call Method
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'So we don't get an error while clearing
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' So Excel will function normal again
    End If

End Function
```

If you are going to change more then one cell at a time use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ChangedCell As Range
    For Each ChangedCell In Target.Cells
        Select Case ChangedCell.Column
            Case 1 'If Target.Column = A
                Call TestValues(ChangedCell, 3)
            Case 2 'If Target.Column = B
                Call TestValues(ChangedCell, 7)
            Case 7 'If Target.Column = G
                Call TestValues(ChangedCell, 1)
        End Select
    Next ChangedCell
End Sub
Function TestValues(curCell As Range, LengthLimit)
        If Len(curCell.Value) <> LengthLimit Then 'The value and length passed in from the Call Method
            MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect Value"
            Application.EnableEvents = False 'So we don't get an error while clearing
            curCell.Value = ""
            curCell.Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True ' So Excel will function normal again
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: i like this!  one problem though...if i select and attempt to delete data from both columns or more than one cell in the same column simultaneously i get a "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch".  Target doesn't seem to be valid in that instance.  is there a way to test if Target is valid and bail if it's not?  i tried this, but it fails also.

`If (Target = vbNull) Then
    Exit Sub
End If`

Comment: disregard, i found it. 

`If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Sorry, for not responding sooner. The best way to handle this situtation to ensure that all the data is still handled is to use `For Each cell In Target.Cells` I have added an edit to cover this. Also, if you feel my answer as fully satisfied your question, please feel free to accept it as the answer!

Comment: N/p.  I think there's one other fix necessary.  I'm pretty sure the offsets should be (0,0).  The -1 was pushing the focus to 1 above the incorrect cell.

Comment: You can adjust as needed but in my personal use. After I change the value and press the enter key the selected cell is usually just under the changed cell, that is why I used that. Sometimes just saying `Target.Value = ""` is all that's needed

Comment: Selecting the cell and this using a reference to the active cell actually would be safer, updated the code.

Comment: use `Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection` to determine which direction the user has set as the default direction to move after pressing `Enter`. `Tab` seems to always be to the right. Seems tough to guess which one they did unless you capture every key press. seems like `target.select` is all you would really need through because that's the originating cell always.

Comment: @Brad `Target` would not be usable in the Function though

Comment: If you pass in the a `range`/`cells` object instead of a string then it would be.

Comment: @Brad Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes'sir. However, I'd say you only need to call it like this `TestValues(ChangedCell, 3)`. you've already established that `ChangedCell` is a single cell at that point.

Comment: I thought that too but, when I ran it like that I got `Compile Error: ByRef Argument Type Mismatch`

Comment: Add `Dim changedcell As Range` as the first line in the change event. Right now I assume you do not have `Option Explicit` at the top of all your code (which you should always have no matter what). `ChangedCell` is a `Variant` (because it wasn't `dim`ed) but you want it to be a `Range`.

Answer (score 2):

The code below tests if the length of the text in the cell is not equal to 8, if so it presents the user with a message box. This is the Worksheet_Change event for the sheet where the data is being entered. Target is the range that was just edited:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Len(Target.Text) <> 8 Then MsgBox "Hey something's wrong!"
End Sub
```

If you want to toggle this functionality off while doing other data entry on the same sheet I would suggest using a cell somewhere on the same sheet to tell the coding that you are in "scanner mode":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If [q1].value <> "" then 'if cell Q1 has any value in it, we are in "scanner mode"
        If Len(Target.Text) <> 8 Then MsgBox "Hey something's wrong!"
    End If
End Sub
```

To test different columns:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If [q1].value <> "" then 'if cell Q1 has any value in it, we are in "scanner mode"
        If Target.Column = 1 then 'if column A do this:
            If Target.Row > 3 and Target.Row < 30 then 'between row 3 and 30
                If Len(Target.Text) <> 8 Then MsgBox "Hey something's wrong!"
            End If
        End If
        If Target.Column = 2 then 'if column B do this:
            If Target.Row > 5 and Target.Row < 50 then 'between row 5 and 50
                If Len(Target.Text) <> 10 Then MsgBox "Hey something's wrong!"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As another enhancement you could ask the user if they want to correct what was entered by hand:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sNewValue As String
    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'if more than 1 cell was changed
    If [q1].Value <> "" Then 'if cell Q1 has any value in it, we are in "scanner mode"
        If Target.Column = 1 Then 'if column A do this:
            If Target.Row > 3 And Target.Row < 30 Then 'between row 3 and 30
                If Len(Target.Text) <> 8 Then
                    sNewValue = InputBox("The scanned value seems invalid, " & _
                        "Press Ok to accept the value or enter different one.", _
                        "Verify Value", Target.Value)
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Value = sNewValue
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If Target.Column = 2 Then 'if column B do this:
            If Target.Row > 5 And Target.Row < 50 Then 'between row 5 and 50
                sNewValue = InputBox("The scanned value seems invalid, " & _
                        "Press Ok to accept the value or enter different one.", _
                        "Verify Value", Target.Value)
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Value = sNewValue
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: well that was easy.  any idea how can i limit the range to a specific column?  or possibly have different length test for column A and column B?

Comment: @alexsd Sure, I just added that to the last bit of code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this might work.

```
Private PreviousSelection As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not PreviousSelection Is Nothing Then
' you have a previous selection, do stuff to it here
End If

Set PreviousSelection = Target

End Sub
```

If your keyboard emulator is sending keys really fast it might struggle though!

If your emulator keeps sending data even after a tab or cr (multiple cells etc) then you will not be able to have a message box to display an error due to the messagebox taking focus away from the worksheet.